# Improve select rows from table1 in table2 but not in table3

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have a SQL Server 2012 database and I'm trying to improve the following sentence:

```
Select c.CodeId from Code c
where c.AggregationLevelId = 2 and CodeId in 
    (select AggregationId from Aggregation where AggregationId not in 
    (select AggregationChildrenId from AggregationChildren))
```

I want to get the rows in `Code` table where its CodeId is in `Aggregation` table but it isn't in table `AggregationChildren`.

It works but it is very slow.

The relationships between the tables are: `Aggregation.AggregationId` and `AggregationChildren.AggregationChildrenId` are FK to `Code.CodeId`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [CodeId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Serial]            NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [ ... ]
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CODE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CodeId] ASC),
    [ ... ]
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aggregation] (
    [AggregationId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [ ... ], 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Aggregation_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregationChildren] (
    [AggregationChildrenId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ ... ],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDREN] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationChildrenId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationChildrenId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId]),
    [ ... ]
)
```

Is there a better way to improve that select?

This is the execution plan for the select:
[image]

Comment: Define 'Very Slow'. How slow? How many records?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I would think a combination of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` would give you what you want.

```
--Setup
set nocount on
DECLARE @Code TABLE (CodeId INT)
DECLARE @Aggregation TABLE (AggregationId INT)
DECLARE @AggregationChildren TABLE (AggregationChildrenId INT)

INSERT INTO @Code (CodeId)
VALUES (1),(2)

INSERT INTO @Aggregation (AggregationId)
VALUES (1),(2)

INSERT INTO @AggregationChildren (AggregationChildrenId)
VALUES (1)

--The query
SELECT c.CodeId
FROM @Code c
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM @Aggregation
        WHERE AggregationId = c.codeid
        )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM @AggregationChildren
        WHERE AggregationChildrenId = c.codeid
        )
```

---

```
| CodeId |
|--------|
| 2      |
```

Comment: I have added the execution plan to the question.

Comment: @VansFannel - are you saying my solution does not give you what you want?

Comment: No, sorry. I have added and I say you if you need it.

Comment: By the way, the select I post does what I want. I only know if  there is another select with better performance.

Comment: Why doesn't my solution give you what you want?  Your question stated you wanted rows from `code` where `codeid` existed in `Aggregation`, but did not exist in `AggregationChildren`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Please, read my comments carefully. I haven't said that.

Comment: Scott, the query you provide is no more efficient than the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried to join the tables instead ?
- Do you have indexes properly set on your FKs ?
- Could you add the query execution plan to your post ?

```
SELECT     c.CodeId  
FROM       Code c   
INNER JOIN Aggregation A        
ON         C.CodeID = A.AggregationId
AND        C.AggregationLevelId = 2     
LEFT JOIN  AggregationChildrenId AC         
ON         C.CodeID = AC.AggregationChildrenId 
WHERE      AggregationChildrenId IS NULL
```

Comment: I have added the execution plan to the question.